# RefinerCMS: Selecting locale from front-end

Tags: refinerycms

I have been crawling Google for the past hour for a solution to this seemingly simple feature.

I have created a RefineryCMS site, and in the settings I've added two frontend locales: en and da. I have also created some pages and translated to both locales. So far so good.

But I simply cannot find out, how I enable the user to select between these two locales from the frontend? Is there some hooks to a "language menu" array and specific locale-select url-helpers?

I have not been able to find anything in the guides. So please help.

TIA

/Carsten

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking just to get to the page?

localhost:3000/ru/about

where ru = russian or whatever your language is.

Not sure how to change the title of the page but that shows the content you've entered in the cms.